# Model binding and ViewBag in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a asp.net core mvc project and implementing search. Defining the `@model IEnumerable<MyObject>`lets me use `@Hhtml.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)` when building the table (headers) which is very convenient.

However this cause issues when implementing a `SearchViewModel` that binds using the query parameters ([FromQuery]) since it isn't the model defined in the Razor view. Therefor I ended up with a wrapper view model to use for the Razor model that has properties for the list of objects and the search view mode. This doesn't feel optimal and also has the side effect of making the query string unnecessary long since the property name is prepended to all searchable properties.

My question is if it is possible to use the `DisplayNameFor` if I pass the `IEnumerable<MyObject>` in the `ViewBag`instead and let the view just pass the search view model.

If there is any option to set different "DataContext" (ViewModel) on certain parts (perhaps using a partial view (never used before)) to achieve this that would be great. This is my first project using ASP.NET Core MVC

Thanks for the help!